# IIS hosting web service asmx /- problem with .net 2.0 / .net 4.0

Tags: amazon-web-services, web, iis, asmx

I have to work on a complex solution which includes a lot of projects. Part of them is web services ( ASMX ). They should be hosted on the local IIS server. The host machine is running under Windows 10.
I set up all projects inside 'Default Web Site' as applications that use .NET 2.0 pool. The project documentation requires to use of .NET 2.0.

When I tried to test web services, I received an error.

**This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded.**

All assemblies are compiled with .NET framework 4.8. I think the project documentation is outdated. There is no sense to have a pool with .NET Framework 2.0. The error is quite understandable.

The most obvious solution is to change the app pool from 2.0 to 4.0. However, when I changed the app pool, the request did not include any response.
It seems the request struggled in a while loop forever.
is there any way to figure out what the problem is with the request?

What seems to be the trouble?
Thanks in advance for any help!

I have checked all windows logs and IIS logs, and there is no clue about that.

Any kind of help will be greatly appreciated!

**#Update on November 19th.**

After switching the pool from 2.0 to 4.0 and issuing the request, the **IIS log does not contain anything connected with the request.**
Output from Fiddler looks like is shown in the image below
[image]

The request is spinning as shown in the image below, colored yellow.
[image]

**It seems that the request is somehow blocked when I changed the pool to 4.0 and works "fine" - produces an error when the pool uses .NET 2.0.**

Both pools have the same security policy as shown in the image below.
[image]
In the windows application log, I have found the following error. The Sensitve data has been replaced with "xxx"

```
Event code: 3005 
Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred. 
Event time: 19-11-22 21:05:46 
Event time (UTC): 19-11-22 20:05:46 
Event ID: 088d23a35f1a4c15bd0d7d5348a1bbf2 
Event sequence: 9 
Event occurrence: 1 
Event detail code: 0 
 
Application information: 
    Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT/XXXXX-2-133133609467131126 
    Trust level: Full 
    Application Virtual Path: /XXX
    Application Path: C:\Git\XXXXX\ 
    Machine name: XXXX
 
Process information: 
    Process ID: 13328 
    Process name: w3wp.exe 
    Account name: OXXXXo 
 
Exception information: 
    Exception type: HttpUnhandledException 
    Exception message: Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown.
   at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestWithNoAssert(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at ASP.defaultwsdlhelpgenerator_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) in c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\storeoffice.webservice\52abe23d\be83241b\App_Web_defaultwsdlhelpgenerator.aspx.cdcab7d2.-o0tklxe.0.cs:line 0
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.DocumentationServerProtocol.WriteReturns(Object[] returnValues, Stream outputStream)

Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
   at System.Collections.ArrayList.ArrayListEnumeratorSimple.MoveNext()
   at ASP.defaultwsdlhelpgenerator_aspx.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\DefaultWsdlHelpGenerator.aspx:line 1413
   at System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

 
 
Request information: 
    Request URL: htXXXXXXX
    Request path: /XXXX
    User host address: ::1 
    User:  
    Is authenticated: False 
    Authentication Type:  
    Thread account name: XXXX
 
Thread information: 
    Thread ID: 21 
    Thread account name: XXXXX 
    Is impersonating: False 
    Stack trace:    at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestWithNoAssert(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at ASP.defaultwsdlhelpgenerator_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) in c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\storeoffice.webservice\52abe23d\be83241b\App_Web_defaultwsdlhelpgenerator.aspx.cdcab7d2.-o0tklxe.0.cs:line 0
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.DocumentationServerProtocol.WriteReturns(Object[] returnValues, Stream outputStream)
 
 
Custom event details:
```

Comment: I have forgotten to write the host machine is running under Windows 10.

Comment: "The most obvious solution is to change the app pool from 2.0 to 4.0" is probably the worst way. If you know how many breaking changes are there from 2.x to 4.x, you shouldn't rush so fast https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/whitepapers/aspnet4/breaking-changes Focus on the error of "This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded" and dig deeper. Learn which assembly is the culprit and see if you can compile it properly against 2.x.

Comment: Thank you for replying. All assemblies are compiled with .NET framework 4.8. I think the project documentation is outdated. There is no sense to have a pool with .NET Framework 2.0. The error is quite understandable. I do not understand why switching to .NET 4.0 does not work. The request in that case never finishes. I am totally desperate.

Comment: Sure. You edited the question so it's better now. Next you might try to edit the question to show us what "the request did not include any response" meant. Did you send a request but never get any response for it? Then did you see that request in IIS logs or HTTP error logs? If you see 500 error in Fiddler, show us the raw response captured by Fiddler (a screen shot for example).

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. The request on localhost is spinning as shown in the image colored yellow. The IIS log does not contain anything connected to the request. I need to correct my previous explanation Fiddler does not contain any output.

Comment: It seems that the request is somehow blocked when I changed the pool to .NET 4.0. What is more, the request works "fine" when the pool is .NET 2.0. Works fine means produces runtime errors. Obviously, the pool should be .NET 4.0, I do not understand why the request is blocked. Basically, it is the same URI, on the same machine/localhost.

Comment: Enable FRT https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules with status code 200-999. Then you might be able to see what happens after the request lands on IIS.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. After enabling FRT, there are no log files. Just a folder and nothing inside. I think the request is somehow blocked.

Comment: Sounds like that FRT article I linked to earlier didn't ask for all providers to be included. Can you revise the rule to include all Trace Providers as showed in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshoot-with-failed-request-tracing ? You also need to review step 5/6 and make sure you enable Site Tracing (or no FRT log will be generated).

Comment: I managed to capture the error in the windows application log, but not sure what it means. ASP.defaultwsdlhelpgenerator_aspx.ProcessRequest

Comment: If you see something in Windows application log, post a screen shot of its full error message.

Comment: I have posted the error. The request tries to get a WSDL description of a web service. The URI is formatted as follows http://localhost/custom.service/webservice.asmx?wsdl

Comment: Is there any way to reinstall .NET 4.0 on IIS? Or to reinstall the complete IIS? I have tried to do that with "Turn windows features On/Off", but this is not a complete re-installation. Everything was memorized.

Comment: Please don't share FRT with others publicly as it might contain confidential information. Like you found out, this application throws exceptions when requests come in, and that's why on browser side the observation is strange. You need to debug the web app on IIS via VS to learn more.

Comment: The exception is thrown in the Microsoft code, not in my code. I am not able to debug that part.

Comment: No. While it sounds like an exception from Microsoft code, it in fact comes from your `ASP.defaultwsdlhelpgenerator_aspx.Page_Load`. Everything is debuggable here if you know the tool to use. Open a support case via https://support.microsoft.com if you are not how.

Comment: DefaultWsdlHelpGenerator is not part of my solution.

Comment: There is a lot behind the scene when an ASP.NET web app is hosted, so I don't plan to explain every details here (as I said enough).